# Table Valued Parameters in Node/Tedious Example

Tags: sql-server, node.js, tedious

I have a function that works really well for executing stored procedures and SQL snippets. I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me make the equivalent function for [Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)?

My current function is as follows:

```js
var exec = function (sql, callback) {
  var request = new Request(sql, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Statement failed: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log(rowCount + " rows");
    }

    callback(err, obj);
  });

  var obj = [];

  request.on("row", function (columns) {
    var values = {};
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
      if (column.isNull) {
        values[column.metadata.colName] = null;
      } else {
        values[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
      }
    });
    obj.push(values);
    //console.log(obj);
    //console.log(" this is the obj in the row function");
  });
  conn.execSql(request);
  //console.log('obj: ' + obj);
  return obj;
};
function columnMetadata(columnsMetadata) {
  columnsMetadata.forEach(function (column) {
    //console.log(column);
  });
}
```

I've done this in SQL to make a table type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.inventoryRequestType AS TABLE
    (
    ItemNo int NULL,
    Qty int NULL,
    Department nvarchar(50) NULL,
    RequestedBy nvarchar(100) NULL
    )
GO
```

And this stored procedure is used to insert using the new table type:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_purchasing_list]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @purchaseList inventoryRequestType READONLY

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [Inventory Requests]
        (
        ItemNo,
        Qty,
        Department,
        RequestedBy
        )
    SELECT
        ItemNo,
        Qty,
        Department,
        RequestedBy
    FROM @purchaseList
END
```

In SQL, the following can be used to execute the stored procedure:

```sql
DECLARE @purchaseList inventoryRequestType

INSERT INTO @purchaseList

SELECT 4444, 1, 'layup', 'marc'

EXEC Purchasing.dbo.create_purchasing_list @purchaseList
```

This is where I get lost. I'm not sure how to make this last part work with [node/tedious](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious).

Here is an example of how I would like to define a table with in the function I need help with. `Columns` and `Rows` variables would be defined by the containing function:

```js
var table = {
  columns: [
    // Columns
    {name: 'id', type: Types.Int},
    {name: 'firstName', type: Types.nvarchar, length: 50},
    {name: 'option', type: Types.Bit}
  ],
  rows: [
    // Rows
    [15, 'Bob', true],
    [16, 'Rob', false]
  ],
};
```

Comment: I now have a function that does everything I need on the database side,

Comment: however it is failing with error,

Comment: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: The following is the function that I have come up with, please help if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I now have a fully functional solution.  It's very dynamic, so I want to share it since I was unable to find a solution in examples here.

This is my **db-functions.js** file that is called by my **app.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var tds = require("tedious");
var Request = require("tedious").Request;
var Types = require("tedious").TYPES;
var ConnectionPool = require("tedious-connection-pool");

var poolConfig = {
  min: 10,
  log: true,
};

var config = {
  userName: "User",
  password: "password",
  server: "192.168.1.123",
  options: {
    requestTimeout: 30 * 1000,
    instanceName: "InstanceOnServer",
    //instanceName: '\SQLServer', // Name of SQL Instance
    rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
    database: "PlantDB",
    encrypt: true,
    debug: {
      data: true, // lots of info generated in console when true
      payload: false,
      token: false,
      packet: true, // was on true
      log: true,
    },
  },
};

var pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfig, config); //multiple connections

pool.acquire(function (err, connection) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("connected");
  }
});

//var conn = new tds.Connection(config);

pool.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

var conn = new tds.Connection(Config);

function requestDone(rowCount, more) {
  console.log(rowCount + "rows------");
  console.log(column);
}

function infoError(info) {
  console.log(info.number + " : " + info.message);
}

function debug(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

var exec = function (sql, callback) {
  // use this function to execute SELECT statements and Stored Procedures

  var request = new Request(sql, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Statement failed: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log(rowCount + " rows");
    }

    callback(err, obj);
  });

  var obj = []; //holds the data generated by the SQL statement when applicable

  request.on("row", function (columns) {
    //identify individual rows
    var values = {}; //insert a value
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
      //identify the column
      if (column.isNull) {
        /*adds a key to the value so that each item in
                           the object is broken into "Column: Value" pairs*/
        values[column.metadata.colName] = null;
      } else {
        values[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
      }
    });
    obj.push(values);
  });
  conn.execSql(request);
  //console.log('obj: ' + obj);
  return obj;
  function columnMetadata(columnsMetadata) {
    columnsMetadata.forEach(function (column) {
      //console.log(column);
    });
  }
};

var storedProcedures = {
  //This is an actual stored procedure that exists in my
  purchasing_list:
    //Purchases Database which is used to identify this object
    {
      fullName: "Purchases.dbo.purchasing_list",
      //fullname of stored procedure
      variable: "purchaseList",
      //the name of my "Table Type" Variable created in SQL
      Columns: [
        { name: "ItemNo", type: Types.Int },
        { name: "ProductName", type: Types.NVarChar },
        { name: "ProductDescription", type: Types.NVarChar },
        { name: "UnitOfMeasure", type: Types.NVarChar },
        { name: "Qty", type: Types.Int },
        { name: "Department", type: Types.NVarChar },
        { name: "RequestedBy", type: Types.NVarChar },
      ],
    },
  another_stored_procedure: {
    fullName: "Purchases.dbo.another_stored_procedure",
    variable: "purchaseList",
    Columns: [
      { name: "ItemNo", type: Types.Int },
      { name: "ProductName", type: Types.NVarChar },
      { name: "ProductDescription", type: Types.NVarChar },
      { name: "UnitOfMeasure", type: Types.NVarChar },
      { name: "Qty", type: Types.Int },
      { name: "Department", type: Types.NVarChar },
      { name: "RequestedBy", type: Types.NVarChar },
    ],
  },
};

var callProc = function (procedureName, Rows, callback) {
  var usefulData = storedProcedures[procedureName];
  var message = "";

  var table = {
    columns: usefulData["Columns"],
    rows: Rows,
    //insert an array of arrays with values defined by storedProcedure
  };

  var request = new Request(usefulData["fullName"], function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Statement failed: " + err);
      message = "There was a problem submitting your request!";
    } else {
      console.log(rowCount + "No errors in TVP");
      //this will likely return an undefined rowCount since this function
      //is generally used to insert and update
      message = "Success";
    }
    callback(err, message);
  });

  request.on("doneProc", function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
    //console.log('Row Count' + rowCount);
    //console.log('More? ' + more);
    //console.log('Return Status: ' + returnStatus);
    //console.log('Rows:' + rows);
  });

  request.addParameter(usefulData["variable"], Types.TVP, table);
  //Add a table type set of parameters to the request to complete the
  //transaction

  conn.callProcedure(request);
};

var insert = function (sql, callback) {
  var request = new Request(sql, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Statement failed: " + err);
      callback = err;
    } else {
      console.log("Insert Statement succeeded");
      callback = "Success";
    }
  });

  conn.execSql(request);
};

var update = function (sql, callback) {
  var insert = "";
  var request = new Request(sql, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      insert = "Statement failed: " + err;
    } else {
      insert = "Insert Statement succeeded";
    }
    callback(err, insert);
  });

  conn.execSql(request);
};

exports.conn = conn;
exports.exec = exec;
exports.callProc = callProc;
exports.insert = insert;
exports.update = update;
```

Within the **App.js** file i've loaded my database like this:

```
var db = require('./public/javascripts/db-functions');
```

A **callProcedure** which allows for multiple rows to be inserted or updated can
be done as follows:

```js
app.route("/update_purchasing").post(function (req, res) {
  var Rows = req.body.Rows;

  db.callProc("create_purchasing_list", Rows, function (err, success) {
    if (err) {
      res.json("Error creating purchasing list: " + err);
    } else {
      res.json("Successfully updated your purchase list");
    }
  });
});
```

The **Rows** might look like this, based on the columns selected in the stored procedure:

```js
var Rows = [
  [0101, "hair gel", "makes your hair stick up", "vat", 1, "house", "Bob"],
  [0102, "carbon", "makes light boats", "roll", 1, "Layup", "Rob"],
];
```

An example of how to execute a stored procedure using **EXEC** my look like this:

```js
app.get("/start", function (req, res) {
  var sess = req.session;

  db.exec(
    "dbo.populate_shipping_schedule" + "parameter1",
    function (err, schedule) {
      if (!err) {
        sess.schedule = schedule;
        res.render("start", { title: "Start" });
      } else {
        console.log("This is an Error: " + err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`var storedProcedures = {
'purchasing_list':
    {
        'fullName': 'Purchases.dbo.purchasing_list',
        'variable': 'purchaseList',
        'Columns' : [
            { 'name': 'ItemNo', 'type': Types.Int }
            , { 'name': 'ProductName', 'type': Types.NVarChar }
            , { 'name': 'ProductDescription', 'type': Types.NVarChar }
            , { 'name': 'UnitOfMeasure', 'type': Types.NVarChar }
            , { 'name': 'Qty', 'type': Types.Int }
            , { 'name': 'Department', 'type': Types.NVarChar }
            , { 'name': 'RequestedBy', 'type': Types.NVarChar }
        ]
    }
}

var callProc = function (procedureName, Rows,callback) {

var usefulData = storedProcedures[procedureName];

var table = {
    columns: usefulData['Columns'],
    rows: Rows          //insert an array of arrays with values defined by storedProcedure
};

var request = new Request(usefulData['fullName'], function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Statement failed: ' + err);
        callback = err;
    } else {
        console.log('No errors in TVP')
        callback = 'Success';
    }

});

request.addParameter(usefulData['variable'], Types.TVP, table);

conn.callProcedure(request);

};`
```

Comment: This completes the insert but errors with net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 1):

Using your statement **"In SQL, the following can be used to execute the stored procedure:"** I've found you can add that to a variable and pass it to your SQL connection and it works just fine.

You can even dynamically add multiple rows to your **TVP** if you replace `(Select 4444,1,'layup', 'marc');` with something like `(Select id,value1,text1, text2 from yourTable)`...

```
var theSQL = DECLARE @purchaseList inventoryRequestType;

theSQL +=  INSERT INTO @purchaseList;

theSQL +=  SELECT 4444, 1, 'layup', 'marc';

theSQL +=  EXEC Purchasing.dbo.create_purchasing_list @purchaseList;

let pool = poolManager.getDBPool(yourpoolmanager)

return await pool.request().query(theSQL)
```